# ArcGIS Server on Windows Server 2008 - .NET or Java Backend

Tags: arcgis-server

I am finding myself having to "defend" why I have chosen to setup ArcGIS Server on .NET backend with IIS (vs Java and Tomcat).  The host server is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I thought I remembered reading some type of ESRI slick stating that ArcGIS Server with .NET and IIS offers better performance vs Java and Tomcat, at least on Windows.  But after a couple hours of searching, I can't find any definitive evidence.

Can anyone state any hard, cold facts as to why ArcGIS Server on .NET and IIS is better on Windows?  Links, comments, personal experiences welcome.

Comment: Also check http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/13438-Java-vs-.NET  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161711/arcgis-development-java-vs-netc

Answer (score 6):

We had both set up in our environment in my previous job. I'm .NET developer and my co-worker preferred Java. We both had our "mine is better than yours" moments.

But .NET has the bigger community online. [.NET Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/9-ArcGIS-Server-.NET) has 1551 threads VS. 355 threads in the [Java's Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/10-ArcGIS-Server-Java)

I suggest you go with the language you're most comfortable with.

---

**UPDATE:**

I hope you're only planning to use .NET or Java for REST and SOAP web services and not ADF.

> ArcGIS Server 10.1 will be the last planned release for the ArcGIS
>   Server Web ADFs (Application Developer Framework) for both Microsoft
>   .NET and Java.

http://geo.geek.nz/esri/deprecation-plans-for-arcgis-10-and-arcgis-10-1/

http://www.esri-ireland.ie/Libraries/Products_-_Desktop_pdfs/ArcGIS_10_and__101_Deprecation_Plan.sflb.ashx

Comment: yeah - I would almost say lean .net more than java. it gets more attention from esri and if some fat were to be trimmed here it would be the java api.

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows environment I don't see much benefit of using the Java edition of AGS. It's another server for you to manage and it's not fully integrated as IIS with Microsoft options. That is, your setup will leak complexity to your code/deploy/maintenance process.

On Windows I would go 100% with IIS and .NET.

Comment: +1 Java edition makes sense for Redhat implementations.  Also worth pointing out that at 10.1 there is no dependency on IIS for either edition.